# Is "is" really necessary to include when specifying a value that is not null, as in "IS NOT NULL" vs "NOT NULL" in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, data-science

I have a question about whether it is really necessary to include "is" when you are trying to state that a value is not null in SQLite. As in.....

`SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL
 AND test IS NOT NULL;`

vs

`SELECT email FROM users
 WHERE campaign NOT NULL
 AND test NOT NULL;`

Both of the commands return the same results. So should I always include the "is"?
The only time that "is" is required is when I try to run a statement that **does** contain a Null value like for example....

`SELECT email FROM users
 WHERE campaign IS NULL
 AND test IS NULL;`

If the "is" is not included it will not return the query that I requested.

So I guess the question is... should I include the "is" if it serves no functionality when a "NOT NULL" value is used?

Comment: The `IS` is part of the standard SQL definition for this syntax.  SQLite might have a synonym, but I would recommend sticking with the standard syntax.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070207/what-is-the-difference-between-is-not-null-and-not-is-null

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [expression syntax diagrams](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), you'll see it supports at the very least:

- `expr ISNULL`
- `expr NOTNULL`
- `expr NOT NULL`
- `expr IS expr`
- `expr IS NOT expr`

for telling if something is `NULL` or not. I'd stick with the last two, as they're the ones people who know other database flavors would expect to see and as mentioned the standard way.